# saving two canvas as a single image in windows store

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am saving canvas as an image in my windows store application like this :

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
 await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(canvas1);
var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
var savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
savePicker.DefaultFileExtension = ".png";
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".png", new List<string> { ".png" }); 
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".jpg", new List<string> { ".jpg" });
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".bmp", new List<string> { ".bmp" }); 
savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "image1.png";
 var saveFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (saveFile == null)
return;
 using (var fileStream = await saveFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
 {
var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, fileStream);
encoder.SetPixelData(
BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
(uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
(uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
pixelBuffer.ToArray());
await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

now i want to save two canvas `i.e canvas1 and canvas2` as a single image . How to do this ?

Comment: The easiest way would be to add both `Canvases` as a `Child` of another `UIElement` and then render out that parent `UIElement` to an image.

Comment: actually i have added some mouse events to that canvas i.e canvas1, when i add another canvas as parent of canvas1 ... mouse events are not working for canvas1